# How to capture function return value with if condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

```
def func1():
    if my_api_success():
        return my_api_value
    else
        return None

x= 1 if func1() is None else func1()
```

I want to capture the return value of `func1()`.
Is it possible to write an one line code, with out calling `func1()` twice?

Comment: It definitely calls it twice. There is though. You can do `x = func1() or 1`.

Comment: why not just use two lines? I can think of no good reason. Python 3.8 will have assignment expressions, which will allow this. So use Python 3.8, or just use two lines. Even if you are using Python 3.8 you should probably just use two lines.

Comment: @CharlieWindolf: Only if all possible values of `my_api_value` are truthy. `or` would be wrong if `func1()` could return `0` or other falsy values.

Comment: That's a good point. So, yeah probably two lines are better.

Comment: `func1` should be raising an exception on a failure, not returning `None`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.8, you can use an assignment expression:

```
x = 1 if (value := func1()) is None else value
```

If you're using an earlier Python version, you can use the `next` function with a generator expression that iterates over a 1-tuple of `func1()` to achieve the same effect of an assignment expression:

```
x = next(1 if value is None else value for value in (func1(),))
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to go with what @CharlieWindolf suggested which is to use:

```
x = func1() or 1
```

The problem with this is that it requires `func1()` to return a value python treats as a boolean.

To fix this you would need to use two lines.

```
y = func1()
x = 1 if y is None else y
```

In Python3.8 this may be possible using an [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) but I have not tested it yet.

```
x = 1 if (y := func1()) is None else y
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just return the value whatever you are trying to check condition for in case of None.

or you could just:
X = func1() 
if X is none X =1